# Debian no inicia sesión, me dice que el disco está lleno

Tags: debian

Debian no inicia sesión, me dice cuando lo ejecuto desde el otro sistema, que el disco está lleno

> df -h

```
S.ficheros     Tamaño Usados  Disp Uso% Montado en
rootfs           124G   117G  1,1G 100% /
udev              10M      0   10M   0% /dev
tmpfs            183M   640K  183M   1% /run
/dev/sda3        124G   117G  1,1G 100% /
tmpfs            5,0M      0  5,0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs            366M   908K  365M   1% /run/shm
/dev/sr0         4,4G   4,4G     0 100% /media/cdrom0
/dev/sda2        166G   158G  6,4G  97% /media/Debian
```

Eso después de hacer

> tune2fs -m 1 /dev/sda2

Comment: Revisa quién es el dueño de tu directorio `~`.

Comment: Revisa en modo single user donde se te acumulan tantos datos en la ruta `root`. Candidato preferido puede ser `/var/log` por ejemplo, en casos de mala configuración de logs, ataques etc.

Comment: Usa el comando `du` para ver cómo está distribuido ese espacio ocupado. Por ejemplo `du -h -d 1 /` (donde `-d` te da el max-depth para que no se vaya recursivo hasta el infinito) y ve revisando qué subdirectorio se está llevando todo

Answer (score 3):

El disco no solo tiene espacio, también tiene inodos. SI estuviera al 100% y con ese espacio, busca en los directorios temporales, pues todo apunta a un servicio tipo nginx, php, memcached, o similar que esta creando microficheros que agotan los inodos, pero no el espacio, y se te ha olvidado alguna tarea programada que limpia esos ficheros.

```
df -i
Filesystem                  Inodes IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev                        252680   434  252246    1% /dev
tmpfs                       256155   402  255753    1% /run
/dev/dm-0                  2559088 99901 2459187    4% /
none                        256155     2  256153    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
none                        256155     2  256153    1% /run/lock
none                        256155     2  256153    1% /run/shm
none                        256155     2  256153    1% /run/user
/dev/sda1                    62248   299   61949    1% /boot
vagrant                       1000     0    1000    0% /vagrant
home_vagrant_phpmyadmin       1000     0    1000    0% /home/vagrant/phpmyadmin
home_vagrant_DataGenerator    1000     0    1000    0% /home/vagrant/DataGenerator
```

Tambien puede intentar, para ver si hay ficheros que aparetemente estan borrados pero no lo estan de forma correcta.

```
sudo lsof +L1
```

Comment: estas en lo correcto, pero no fue el caso, lo hice también y no aparecian deleted

Comment: @CarlosCelis pues si estab en lo correcto, por favor puntua como positivo, la respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

Gracias a todos por sus respuestas, en efecto se habían acabado los inodos y se me fue **"consumiendo el disco"** sin darme cuenta

Lo repare al final arrancando el otro sistema y ejecutando

```
e2fsck -f /dev/sda2
```

Al final recuperé cerca de 20 GB que tenía "robados" en la tabla de partición

Answer (score -1):

Inicia la sesion con el usuario root y la respectiva contraseña. Luego instala bleachbit y selecionando todo menos (dentro de la categoria Sistema) "Memoria" y "Liberar espacio libre", hace una limpieza al sistema. Puede ser que el cache del sistema halla llenado la partición /.

Comment: Como se instala una herramienta en un disco lleno?

Comment: El usuario ya ha reiniciado el sistema, luego el cache no esta lleno. luego no puede instalar software. El 99,99% de los problemas de administracion de sistemas no requieren software de terceros. Simplemente requieren conocer el sistema.

Comment: Rnd, tenes 1 gb de espacio en / disponible. Y abkrim ya sé que para un problema así de administración no sea necesariamente necesario un programa de tercero pero acá estoy tratando de hacerle las cosas lo más simple posible.

Comment: no pude ni siquiera presionar <tab> porque no podía crear archivos temporales